# How to evaluate mongodb shard clusters redundancy level?

Tags: mongodb

I am new with mongodb and tried to touch base with mongo db documentation.

Here is the word I saw "Each shard is a replica set"? Does that mean, if I have 10 shards, then each data set I will have 10 copies in the distributed system? If that is the case, what is the point and can the redundancy level be tuned to like 2, since if I have 30 shards and redundancy level set to 2 are already suffice to the high availability. Or am I misunderstanding some mongo db terminologies?

Answer (score 5):

After reading documentation more throughly. I am answering my own question here.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-members/

The "redundancy level" of mongo db of shard cluster is through replica sets. 
The replica sets has a concept of members, the number of members usually mean the number of redundancies of data. The minimum of the redundancies level: replica set should have at least 3 members but since one can be arbiter which does not hold data, so it is 2. The max is 12 as documentation mentioned.

Replica set members can be configured here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to imagine this is to read up on replica sets first: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/

Once you read that, just the introduction, it will make complete sense, however, I will provide a little bit of detail now.

So MongoDB provides HA (High Availability) via replica sets. These are a set of `mongod`s which hold a up to date or delayed mirror of each other (you can have delayed members for backup etc).

So a replica set represents a redundant cluster of your data with a copy of your data on each member of the set.

A replica set in a sharded setup would mean that each shard is in fact, hopefully, at least 3 servers in itself which provide the HA for the range of data that the shard holds.

Comment: I understand that. My question is why you need a copy on every mongod. Think of the high availability, if you have 100 servers, with two copies of the data randomly distributed on two mongod your availability is already 1 - (1/100) * (1/99) = 99.98%. Why waste to put the other 98 copies on the servers, which means if you have 100 servers, you have to replicate the write to another 99 servers for each write, is that a huge waste of network bandwidth and cpu even though that is asynchronous?

Comment: @ShaozhenDing When you say: " Does that mean, if I have 10 shards, then each data set I will have 10 copies in the distributed system" I'm not sure you do. That isn't how sharding works. No with 2 membe replica sets your availability will actually be no better than one due to failover clauses, 50% is not enough of a majority to elect a new primary. The other copies come under the CAP theory of partition tolerance

Comment: Thanks for your response. "I'm not sure you do", then how many copies you had, my question is how can you tune them. "50% is not enough of a majority", how did you get the 50%. Like the example above I gave. If you have 100 servers and redundancy level to two copies, you obtain 99.98% availability if two random servers of 100 servers down.

Comment: @ShaozhenDing each shard holds its own unique range, as such the number of copies will be decided by the minimum number of members you have in each of the 10 replica sets. If the redundancy level is 2 copies that mans you have two members to each set, when you get failover , i.e. one server goes down you will actually not be able to elect a new primary since MongoDB elections work via a quorum, you need the majority of configured members online to maintain availability.

Comment: @ShaozhenDing the sort of base level you should maintain is actually 3 for partition and failover tolerance

Comment: @ShaozhenDing I am also not sure if you can quantify the availability here as a percentage, you would have to take a lot more than just number of copies into account, you would have to judge CAP and latency and freak events, and other such things as such I cannot really relate to your percentages there, I can only give you an availability level really

Comment: "each shard holds its own unique range, as such the number of copies will be decided by the minimum number of members you have in each of the 10 replica sets" So you mean the redundancy is automatically determined by Mongo, what do you mean the "minimum number of members" and what decide the minimum number of members have in each of 10 replica sets. And I am not sure our discussion is related to  CAP at all....:) Or you can assume that C, A, P is predetermined for the continuing discussion.

Comment: @ShaozhenDing kind of the redundancy is decided by the number of replica members you have. One thing to understand here is that replica sets are the MongoDB definition of CAP and it decides your availability in a distributed setup. Replica sets are designed to give fault and partition tolerance aka HA in relation to CAP as such the use of CAP here is definitive, but I will stop and talk more about actually explaining the setup

Comment: @ShaozhenDing "what do you mean the "minimum number of members"" ok so imagine you have 10 shards, each holding 10 unique ranges of a users collection, lets say 1b / 10 as such each shard holds 100,000,000 users. If you have 5 members to the first 5 shards but only 2 members to the next 5 shards your availability is actually only level 2

Comment: @ShaozhenDing sorry realised my English was terrible in my last reply: "each holding 10 unique ranges of a users collection" was supposed to be "each holding a unique range of a user collection"

Comment: @ShaozhenDing and to be even clearer when I say say 5 members I mean each shard is a replica set of 5 members

Comment: Thank you very much Sammaye. I read more about documentation along with your comment. I am answer my own question straight below.